# Deleted posts don't clear from flag cache

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging, review, 10k-tools

I noticed a bug recently, and I came across it today again which reminded me to report.

Sometimes a very low-quality post is made, usually by a transient new user, which is automatically flagged by the system; as well as several users who flag it as low quality or "not an answer". It used to be the case that these posts would accumulate flags until the moderators deleted them; then trusted users were allowed to delete those posts themselves. Both these actions automatically clear the flags.

However with the introduction of the new review system, ordinary users (read: not trusted or moderators) can vote to delete answers and if there are enough recommendations to delete, the post actually gets deleted. Although it doesn't say that it got deleted after being reviewed by six users or so.

I noticed that sometimes(?) flags being made on the posts are not cleared up. This causes the post to appear in the flagging queue despite being deleted, and what's worse is that I can't really flag or vote to delete... because it's already deleted!

> **Example:** [A proof of the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192565/a-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-symmetric-polynomials/292358#292358) and [here is the review log](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/43189) (obviously only 10k+ can see this, and only diamond mods should be able to see the flags; I'm not sure who can see the review log).

While I'm at it, perhaps change the "Deleted" text to point to the review log in the post itself? It would be as reasonable as writing the names of those who voted to delete in the ordinary case.

Comment: Perhaps they are cleared periodically, instead of immediately upon deletion? Many changes caused by deleted posts, like rep updates, happen after a short delay when the garbage-collecting process goes through them. Might that be consistent with what you saw?

Comment: But deleting an answer otherwise does that immediately.

Comment: Just a note: I can see the review log (not 10k+, not diamond obviously), but even there not the answer, only the question and who voted on deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10k users were seeing all posts with moderator flags on them, whether they were deleted or not.

Next build corrects this issue, so you shouldn't be seeing deleted posts on the 10k tools unless you are a moderator.

Comment: The point was that usually closing a question, or deleting a question would clear the flag; but not in this case. Deleting from the review doesn't clear the flags. Also, if possible the list of the deleting committee in case of a review deletion would be nice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - It could happen that a moderator flag was added after the question was closed and before deletion. Or that the flag was added after deletion (rare, but can happen).

Comment: As for the feature request... something for MSO.

Comment: I was under the great impression that feature requests were monitored throughout the meta sites, and that is why there is a [feature-request] tag on every meta. Also, I am fully aware to the way the flagging system works.

Comment: @Asaf - Didn't mean disrespect.

Comment: No offense was taken. :-)